# Javascript - ручная сортировка

Tags: javascript, сортировка, функции, циклы

Есть недоделанная функция сортировки, которая должна находить минимальный элемент массива и засовывать его в новый массив. Так как я не знаю, как удалить предыдущий минимальный эллемент, функция выдает массив из одного самого минимального числа из данного ей массива(например `[44, 5, 2, 6, 3]` она выдает `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, вместо `[2, 3, 5, 6, 44]`)

Мне нужно дополнить/подправить код ниже, а не новый или сокращенный вариант. Я хочу понять, как это работает через функции и циклы, сколько только я разных способов не перепробовал - все напрасно:

```
function sort(arr) {
    var sorted = [];
    var min = Infinity;
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min ) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
        }
        sorted.push(min);
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: `arr.splice(i, 1)` - удалит элемент

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов привёл вас к решению, стоит отметить его как верный — зелёная галочка слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код в вопросе мягко говоря не оптимален, но его можно "исправить" )

```
function sort(arr) {
    var sorted = [];
    var min = Infinity;
    var minIndex = Infinity;
    for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < min ) {
                min = arr[i];
                minIndex = i;// нужен предполагаемый индекс минимума кроме самого минимума, чтобы убрать его из исходного массива
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = Infinity;// исходный массив надо поправить, в нем нет больше "найденного минимального элемента, поставим бесконечность, чтобы была больше любого"
        sorted.push(min);
        min = Infinity;// надо сбрасывать минимум, иначе в следующей итерации не найдем ничего меньше, либо инициализиировать переменную внутри первого for
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mins = []; //сюда будем записывать минимумы

//массив массивов
var arr = [
  [10, 1, 5, 3, 6],
  [65, 21, 45, 32, 16],
  [300, 20, 25, 78, 6015],
];

var absMin = arr[0][0]; //мимимум по всем строкам

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var row = arr[i];

  //поиск минимума в строке
  var min = row[0];
  for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
    var num = row[j];
    if (num < min) min = num;
    if (num < absMin) absMin = num;
  }

  mins.push(min);
}

document.write('Минимальные элементы в каждой строке:<br> [' + mins.join(', ') + ']');
document.write('<hr>');
document.write('Абсолютный мимимум:<br>' + absMin);
```

Демонстрация работы тут https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/MJdmWm

Comment: Вы меня не так поняли, мне нужно из  [44, 5, 2, 6, 3] получить [2, 3, 5, 6, 44], но спасибо за ваш код, будет интересно в нем разобраться!

Answer (score 0):

Сразу не понял постановку задачи:

```
var nums = [44, 5, 2, 6, 3];
nums.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });

document.write('[' + nums.join(', ') + ']');
```

рабочий пример тут https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/jyomyB

Comment: Простите, но это тоже не то что мне надо, я хочу сам написать функцию сортировки,  как в коде что я кинул, только там пару строк не хватает, чтоб удалялись предыдущие минимальные числа

Answer (score 0):

Так что ли?

```js
console.info([44, 5, 2, 6, 3].sort((a, b) => a > b));
```

Не надо создавать велосипед в данном случае.
Будет тормозить (относительно нативной реализации) и поддерживать сложно.

Но всё же:

```js
let arr = [44, 5, 2, 6, 3];

const sort = a => {
  let len = a.length - 1;
  
  // Проход каждому элементу
  for(let i = 0; i < len; i++)
      // Проводим элемент по массиву
      for(var e = 0; e < len - i; e++)
        // Если элемент больше следующего
        if(a[e] > a[e + 1])
          // То флипаем его (меняем местами)
          [a[e], a[e + 1]] = [a[e + 1], a[e]];
  
  return a;
};

console.info(sort(arr));
```

Comment: да так, только я именно и хочу велосипед, чтоб разобратсья

Comment: @SeerPauka, так?

Comment: это немного не то, я хочу не менять их местами, а создать новый массив, искать самое маленькое число, пушить его в новый массив, например [44, 5, 2, 6, 3] нашли 2,  запушили, дальше удаляем 2 и 3 теперь минимальное, ищем его, пушим и так далее, но я не знаю как удалить предыдущее минимальное число

Comment: @SeerPauka, Кажется Вы сами не понимаете что хотите. После пуша, числа опять становятся безликими в данном контексте. Зачем напрягаться, пример "ручной" сортировки я привёл.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea rows="5" name="source" placeholder="Введите элементы массива через запятую">44, 5, 2, 6, 3</textarea>
<br>
<button name="do_sort">Выполнить сортировку</button>
<br>
<br>
<h2>Результат</h2>
<textarea rows="5" name="result"></textarea>

<script>
  var btn = document.querySelector('button[name="do_sort"]'),
    source = document.querySelector('textarea[name="source"]'),
    result = document.querySelector('textarea[name="result"]');

  btn.onclick = function() {
    try {
      var arr = JSON.parse("[" + source.value + "]");
      result.value = BubbleSort(arr).join(', ');
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Ошибка в исходных данных");
    }
  };

  /** сортировка методом пузырька
   * @param A - массив, который нужно отсортировать по возрастанию
   */
  function BubbleSort(A) {
    var n = A.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++) {
        if (A[j + 1] < A[j]) {
          var t = A[j + 1];
          A[j + 1] = A[j];
          A[j] = t;
        }
      }
    }
    return A; // На выходе сортированный по возрастанию массив A.
  }
</script>
```

Ссылка на рабочий пример https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/EZzEEx